# How to populate JSF inputText with initial value and submit control value to another property?

Tags: jsf

Let's say 
I have

```
 <h:dataTable var="s" value#{somebean.properties}>
 <h:column>
  <h:inputText initial=#{s.min} value=#{somebean.mintmp}/>
  <h:commandButton action=#{filterbean.addProretryFilter(s.id, somebean.mintmp)} />
 </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

"initail" attribute don't exit in inputText.
Is there any way to implement desired functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind your input text field to backing bean and initialize it in constructor or @PostConstruct and set the initial value.

```
   @ManagedBean 
   public class Bean{

      private HtmlInputText inputComponent = new HtmlInputText();
      private String min = "5";
      private String minData;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init(){
        inputComponent.setValue(min);
      }

      //....get/set other logic

    }
```

In view you can have

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.minData}" binding="#{bean.inputComponent}"></h:inputText>
```

Comment: This won't work in OP's case where the value depends on the current datatable row object.

Comment: @gbagga can you provide a sample (or just an idea) how to use our suggestion in case inputText is inside of dataTable?

Comment: @avgusti have a look at this [link](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/06/using-datatables.html) you might get some pointer.

Comment: For some reason this method was not called when I write on the managed bean, but it works on the Entity Bean, with PostLoad.

Answer (score 0):

in your managed bean's getter you could return a default value. E.g.

```
private String mintmp=null;

public String getMintmp()
{
   if(mintmp == null)
     return "default min";
   return mintmp;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not what the OP wants. In your example the default value will be saved on form submit and that is not desired. You could adapt the setter as well to ignore default value.

Comment: yes, but that's an easy fix. We just add another check in the setter to see if it is a default value.

Comment: Actually my case is population of list with acceptable values.

Comment: A simple sample - user wants to purchase laptop that costs between 1K- 2K. Database contains prices in range 500-3k. properties are saved in a value- key table so laptop may have any number of properties for filtering. So page shows possible ranges and adding filter values to list.  I don't see any "non desired OP approach" in such solution. @JustasAzna - thank you. That's the way I've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your design. Even without populating the default value, you have a problem. This pseudocode is roughly analogous to your logic:

```
//beans
SomeBean somebean = ...
DataModel model = ...
FilterBean filterbean = ...
//apply request values phase
for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++) {
  model.setRowIndex(i)
  S s = model.getRowData()
  //inputText's state is set to the submitted row state by the dataTable
  Object submittedValue = inputText.getSubmittedValue()
  somebean.mintmp = submittedValue
}
//invoke application phase
for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++) {
  model.setRowIndex(i)
  S s = model.getRowData();
  //commandButton's state is set to the submitted row state by the dataTable
  if(commandButton.clicked()) {
    filterbean.addProretryFilter(s.id, somebean.mintmp)
  }
}
```

`somebean` will always be populated with the last row value.

See the [JSF lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/#figure1) and the [DataModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Use primefaces! There's this really nice update attribute on buttons that update the components you want to refresh. It's magical.